# Positioning div with css and flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I am trying to simply layout some divs and make some contents with fixed widths and other reflowable.

[image]

For example, the upper image shows the configuration for a minimum width. The below image shows what should happen when window is enlarged. Actually, most of items stick to right or left but only one input is intended to enlarge.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div style="flex-grow: 1">
      <div class="flex-container">
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">An Input</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 120;">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">An Input</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 120;">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">An Input</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-container">
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 1;">An Input</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">Btn</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">Big Btn</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is parent div width set to 100%?

Comment: Can you add one example of problematic code you've tried please?

Comment: Given that you, mostly, have the code to implement what you want, it might be a good idea to either add your own answer, or add the functional code to the answer you accepted. Personally, I'd probably do the latter, given that you had not provided the MCVE prior to getting the accepted answer, and you implemented it based on that answer.

Comment: Use auto margin ... on the "Some label" `<div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 120;margin-left: auto;">Some label</div>` and it will push the rest with it.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/waczx4nf/ ... and no spacer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second image shows a misconception about how flex works. Flex stretches to fill the container. Therefore the second image is not possible.

The first row in the second image looks like a float layout. To achieve the same in flex you need to add an additional empty element that will fill the void, but does not have visible content.

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div style="flex-grow: 1">
      <div class="flex-container">
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">An Input</div>
         <!-- Adding a "spacer" solves the issue -->
         <div style="flex-grow: 1;"></div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 120;">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">An Input</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 120;">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">An Input</div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-container">
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">Some label</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 1;">An Input</div>
         <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">Btn</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0">Big Btn</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course the second is possible, using auto margins: https://jsfiddle.net/waczx4nf/ ... no spacer element needed

Comment: It does work too yes, thanks for that. would one be preferable on the other ?

Comment: If there is a property that does the job one shouldn't add stray element's in the markup. You should then also remove stuff like _"...second image is not possible."_ and _"you need to add an additional empty element"_ from the answer, as those statements are wrong.